# Regex.Replace formatting a query

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am working in VB.Net and trying to use Regex.Replace to format a string I am using to query Sql.  What Im going for is to cut out comments "--".  I've found that in most cases the below works for what I need.

```
string = Regex.Replace(command, "--.*\n", "")
```

and

```
string = Regex.Replace(command, "--.*$", "")
```

However I have ran into a problem.  If I have a string inside of my query that contains the double dash string it doesn't work, the replace will just cut out the whole line starting at the double dash.  It makes since to me as to why but I can't figure out the regular expression i need to match on.

logically I need to match on a string that starts with "--" and is not proceeded by "'" and not followed by "'" with any number of characters inbetween.  But Im not sure how to express that in a regular expression.  I have tried variations of:

```
string  = Regex.Replace(cmd, "[^('.*)]--.*\n[^(.*')]", "")
```

Which I know is obviously wrong.  I have looked at a couple of online resources including http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx
but due to my lack of understanding I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: is there a `;` at the end of each of your statement? if yes, you could consider to match `-- lines` that are following `;`, say `;\s*--`...

Comment: It is a whole lot easier to find things that are in quotes than to find things that are NOT in quotes, but it would be rather simple if, as @Kent asks, all of your lines ended with `;`'s: `(?<=;)\s*--.*\r\n`

Comment: Are you doing this to prevent / help prevent injection attacks etc?

Comment: sorry there is not a ; at the end of the line as in VB.net my lines aren't ended with ;.  and no it is not to prevent injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant "match on a string that starts with `--` and is not <del>proceeded</del>preceeded by `'` and not followed by `'` with any number of characters inbetween"

If so, then this is what you are looking for:

```
string  = Regex.Replace(cmd, "(?<!'.*?--)--(?!.*?').*(?=\r\n)", "")
'EDIT: modified a little
```

Of course, it means you can't have apostrophes in your comments... and would be exceedingly easy to hack if someone wanted to (you aren't thinking of using this to protect against injection attacks, are you? ***ARE YOU!??!*  :D** )

I can break down the expression if you'd like, but it's essentially the same as my modified quote above!

**EDIT:**

I modified the expression a little, so it does not consume any carriage return, only the comment itself... the expression says:

```
(?<!     # negative lookbehind assertion*
  '      #   match a literal single quote
  .*?    #   followed by anything (reluctantly*)
  --     #   two literal dashes
)        # end assertion
--       # match two literal dashes
(?!      # negative lookahead assertion
  .*?    #   match anything (reluctant)
  '      #   followed by a literal single quote
)        # end assertion
.*       # match anything
(?=      # positive lookahead assertion
  \r\n   #   match carriage-return, line-feed
)        # end assertion
```

- *negative lookbehind assertion* means at this point in the match, look backward here and assert that this cannot be matched
- *negative lookahead assertion* means look forward from this point and assert this cannot be matched
- *positive lookahead* asserts the following expression CAN be matched
- *reluctant* means only consume a match for the previous atom (the `.` which means everything in this case) if you cannot match the expression that follows. Thus  the `.*?` in `.*?--` (when applied against the string `abc--`) will consume `a`, then check to see if the `--` can be matched and fail; it will then consume `ab`, but stop again to see if the `--` can be matched and fail; once it consumes `abc` and the `--` can be matched (success), it will finally consume the entire `abc--`

  - *non-reluctant or "greedy"* which would be `.*` without the `?` will match `abc--` with the `.*`, then try to match the end of the string with `--` and fail; it will then *backtrack* until it can match the `--`
- one additional note is that the `.` "anything" does not by default include newlines (carriage-return/line-feed), which is needed for this to work properly (there is a switch that will allow `.` to match newlines and it will break this expression)

A good resource - where I've learned 90% of what I know about regex - is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/)

Tread carefully and good luck!

Comment: no it is not to prevent injection attack.  its just a requirement.  and if you want to break it down I would appreciate that.  I would help me in the future.

Comment: tested this and it works the way I need.  I would love to have a resource or an explanation so I can use the knowlege going forward.  I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: @ChrisSantiago Just in case you hadn't noticed, I added the explanation and a link to the most comprehensive general regex resource I know of!

Comment: Yes!  Its helped me out greatly and I appreciate the time and effort you put in to answer my question, and go the extra mile.  Thank you.

Comment: Above solution not working with 1'or'1'='1 this string :(

Answer (score 0):

OK what you are doing here is not right :

```
/[^('.*)]--.*\n[^(.*')]/
```

You are saying the following :

Do not match a (, ), ', ., * then match -- then match anything until a newline and to not match the same character class as the one at the start.

What you probably meant to do is this :

```
/(?<!['"])\s*--.*[\r\n]*/
```

Which says, make sure that you don't match a `'` or `"` match any whitespace match `--` and anything else until the end or a newline or line feed character.

Comment: Caret `^`: the most most misunderstood meta character in regex.